# Wrong date in NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am creating a NSDate. Why the day is always one less?

This is the code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:today];
[comps setDay:31];
NSDate *lastDayOfMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
NSLog(@"last %@",lastDayOfMonth);
```

this is the log:

```
last 2013-12-30 23:00:00 +0000
```

the result is 30 instead of 31

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between NSDate and NSDateComponent value for the same date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555627/difference-between-nsdate-and-nsdatecomponent-value-for-the-same-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last 2013-12-30 23:00:00 +0000
```

It is because you are being *shown* the time as GMT - that is, the time in London. But you are not in London. I don't know where you are, but if you think about it you will realize that when it is 2300 hours on the 30th in London, it is midnight on the 31st where you are, which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, but how do I change the last number from +0000 to current timezone?

Comment: Make your own NSDateFormatter instead of using the default one as you are doing above. The default date formatter uses GMT time zone. If you make your own NSDateFormatter you can set its `timeZone` to whatever you like. For example you can set it to `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`.

Comment: But that is not the point. The point is that you are in fact getting the right answer. You just don't know it when you see it because you are not looking carefully at it. An NSDate must be displayed as *some* time zone, and if you look at the time zone being used here, you will see that the answer you are getting is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

- [NSDate date] returns 'now'
- you ask for the year, day and month of this date, not for time elements
- you set the day to 31
- you ask the calendar to convert 31/thismonth/thisyear with notime to an NSDate
- logging the NSDate prints out the time in UTC, and as it has not hours and minutes, these are apparently set to 23:00, which is just one hour before the correct date.

In short, it seems like a timezone or daylight-savings time to me.

All this calendar time-calculations can be very confusing, so a a general recommendation: watch the WWDC 2012 and  WWDC 2013 about a calendrical computations (especially the 2012 version).